# Binding Enum Name to a DataTextField

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, kendo-ui

I'm binding an IEnumerable object to a Kendo ComboBox using Razor, but having a little trouble populating the correct DataTextField value.

Model

```
public class LanguageInformation
    {
        public Languages Language { get; set; }
        public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    }
```

Languages Enum

```
public enum Languages
    {
        English = 1,
        Spanish = 2,
        French = 3,
        German = 4
    }
```

Razor

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("Language")
    .DataTextField("Language")
    .DataValueField("LanguageId")
)
```

(Note: data source is defined and returning data fine, just haven't included it above)

The issue I'm having is that the DataTextField. I want to Name of the Languages enum, but am at a loss as to how to return it.

I've tried a few different things such as

```
.DataTextField(Enum.GetName(typeof(Languages), "Language"))
```

But that results in a

> value passed in must be an enum base

error

So, how to I return the name of the enum value as the DataTextField?

Answer (score 0):

Kendo does not traditionally bind to Enums, but to lists instead.
You can make a list out of an Enum with the following code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("Language")
    .BindTo(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Languages)).ToList()
)
```

Comment: That's helpful, but not actually what I was after. I'm not trying to bind directly to an enum, but trying to get the name part of an enum for the datatextvalue when the value is passed through as part of the datasource.

Comment: Oh. Why don't just just convert the enum to the proper string on the back-end?

Comment: That's what I'm going to have to do. The general idea was to have the controller as lightweight as possible, almost acting purely as a pass through and do all the formatting on front end. It's looking less and less like that's going to happen though. Thanks for the help

Comment: I see. Yeah the .DataTextField() should just be a string that references one field in the data object holding your value pairs of data. And in the case of the text it is generally a string. I am guessing you are getting the actual value of the enum right (the int)?

Comment: Yeah, just the int value. Took me a little while to understand what it was doing and why (late night, don't ask), but modifying the model to pass the text as a separate field worked fine, cheers.